# How to install arm-none-eabi-gdb, gdb, openocd, gcc for STM32 toolchain?

Tags: software-installation

Trying to install a toolchain for an STM32F4 Discovery Eval Board. Any hints about doing this?

```
sudo apt-get install arm-none-eabi-gdb
```

If at all possible I would like to avoid using an IDE. So that I can get the hang of the basics.

Leaning towards using `dfu-util` or Texane st-link

Answer (score 2):

Worked for me on Ubuntu 16.04:

```
sudo apt install gdb-arm-none-eabi
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with Ubuntu 18.04.
To install “gcc-arm-none-eabi” on Ubuntu 18.04.

> sudo apt-get install gcc-arm-none-eabi

Using this command system install all binary into **/usr/bin** folder. But Some binaries are not found here. so, I am using its alternative way as below. it's working for me.

If you want to use below arm-none-eabi utility.

> arm-none-eabi-gdb
>
> arm-none-eabi-as
>
> arm-none-eabi-objcopy

Download the ARM-GCC toolchain from [gnu-mcu-eclipse/arm-none-eabi-gcc](https://github.com/gnu-mcu-eclipse/arm-none-eabi-gcc/releases)

I have downloaded "gnu-mcu-eclipse-arm-none-eabi-gcc-6.3.1-1.1-20180331-0618-centos64" for my x64 System.

After downloaded successfully Extract the compressed file.  Go to

> /gnu-mcu-eclipse-arm-none-eabi-gcc-6.3.1-1.1-20180331-0618-centos64/gnu-mcu-eclipse/arm-none-eabi-gcc/6.3.1-1.1-20180331-0618/bin

Copy the GDB and objcopy into **/usr/bin** Directory

> sudo cp arm-none-eabi-gdb /usr/bin/
>
> sudo cp arm-none-eabi-objcopy /usr/bin/

After copy you can use the GCC and GDB.

Answer (score 0):

They are actually compliant.

The GCC ARM tool chain does not compile for Cortex-M4 and Cortex-M2. (However code for Cortex-M3 is suitable for Cortex-M4.) And it gives only ELF output.

I'm currently working at the software and am able to transform ELF into HEX suitable for at least some programmers. It must be some commercial software, which make sense for free GCC, and OpenOCD apart, but not together.

Also, there are no available, even basic, libraries for STM-32. I plan to develop them too. But I plan to do it step by step for each task. (Many years ago I codded for [PIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PIC_microcontroller) without any libraries, simply giving defining every resource I need. I may share my next job with step by step growing libraries. But it may take some while.)